# Powershell script to list all users that have message delivery restrictions in exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter {AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom -ne $Null}
```

This code only return few users and it shows `ProhibitSendQuota`,
I would like to return all users that have message delivery restrictions configured to accept messages from and reject messages from.

*Additional info: the users are located in `sample.net/sample DIV OU/IDM_Users`

Answer (score 0):

Looking back through my Exchange Scripts, I have this for getting Delivery Restrictions:

```
Get-Mailbox –ResultSize Unlimited |
    Where-Object {$_.AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers –ne "" –or $_.RejectMessagesFromSendersOrMembers –ne ""} |
    Select Name,Alias,AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers,RejectMessagesFromSendersOrMembers
```

I'm not able to test it as I don't use Exchange anymore, but it should still be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by using the following query.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit "OU=SAMPLE DIV OU ,DC=SAMPLE,DC=NET" |
where-object {$_.AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers –ne “” –or $_.RejectMessagesFromSendersOrMembers –ne “”} | 
select Name, alias, AccpetMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers, RejectMessagesFromSendersOrMembers
```

The Get-Mailbox cmdlet has a -OrganizationalUnit parameter that I used to target the OU.